# PHP inserts null at end of string

Tags: php

I've been writing simple api for my website and when function displays string it appends with null at the end of

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);

class EnterData {

function addPlayedGames ($games) {
    echo $games;
}

}

switch ($_GET['method']) {
    case 'say':
            $response = 'Hello';
        break;
    case '':
            $response = 'No method has been called';
        break;
    case 'addToPlayCount':
            $enter_data = new EnterData();
            $response = $enter_data->addPlayedGames($_GET['games']);
        break;

    default:
            $response = 'Unknown method | Error 01';
        break;
}


if(!isset($_GET['method'])){
    $response = 'Nothing has been passed.';
}

@header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

E.g.

> examle.com/api.php?method=addToPlayCount&games=31293123

displays

> 31293123null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function doesn't return anything.

```
function addPlayedGames ($games) {
    echo $games;
}
```

[Functions that don't explicitly `return` a value will implicitly return null.](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values)

So when you use that function here:

```
$response = $enter_data->addPlayedGames($_GET['games']);
```

`$response` is set to `null`, and `json_encode(null)` returns the string "null".